# No instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to Message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc-java

I have a field called "key" of type `google.protobuf.Any`. I know that this is a String, so I'd like to "cast" it using the `unpack()` method.

However, when I write `request.getKey().unpack(String.class)`, I get a compilation error:

```
Required type: Class<T>
Provided: Class<String>
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to Message
```

I don't really understand what this really means.

This is my proto file:

```
message SearchCriteria{
  google.protobuf.Any key = 1;
  string storeName = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some protobuf type:
`<T extends com.google.protobuf.Message>`

Comment: In that case StringValue.class